# Laravel Many To Many relation returns null

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class User with many to many relation with itself

```
public function following(){//Many To Many relationship
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_users', 'username', 'follower');
}
public function followers(){//Many To Many relationship
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_users', 'follower', 'username');
}
```

I made the table migration users_users:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->string('username');
        $table->foreign('username')->references('username')->on('users');

        $table->string('follower');
        $table->foreign('follower')->references('username')->on('users');
    });
}
```

and when I try to get the followers of one user, it returns me an empty array when the table is filled with relations.

```
public function getFollowers(String $username){
    $user = User::where('username',$username)->get();
    if(!$user){//si no ha encontrado el user con ese id
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not found'],404);
    }
    return response()->json(['followers' => $user[0]->followers],200);
}
```

Any idea? :/

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `username` instead of `id` in the pivot table? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I wanted to be username the primary Key but i couldn' change it.
i'm going to use the id now to see if it fixes it

Comment: I'm using Laravel Framework 5.7.11

Comment: It works perfect with the ID instead of the username, Thank you so much